# Java remove part of file path

Tags: java, path, zip

Using http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Makingazipfileofdirectoryincludingitssubdirectoriesrecursively.htm slightly modified to zip directories up into a zip, I am left with this:

source path

```
E:someDir/someDir/somefile
```

and path in .zip

```
E:someDir/someDir/somefile
```

waht I would like to get in the .zip is

```
someDir/somefile
```

though, how to achieve this, if the full dir path will be varying between users of the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example from your post, this line is what needs to be modified:

```
out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getAbsolutePath()));
```

should be

```
out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("someDir/somefile"));
```

But then you should be able to derive `someDir/somefile` from the complete source path `E:someDir/someDir/somefile`. You should be able to do this either by substrings or by appending [File.getParentFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile%28%29)